# Как создать массив класса

Tags: c#, массивы

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно ранее определённый класс задать в другом классе как масив.
Я делаю следующее:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Evnt 
{
    public Data[] views { get; set; }
    public Evnt(int i)
    {
        views = new Data[i];
    }
}
```

Получаю одно и то же значение во всех индексах.

Answer (score 2):

```
Data value = new Data();
value.Name = 'Name 1';

List<Data> list = new List<Data>();
list.Add(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, на шарпе не работаю. Но есть подозрение, что вы делаете что-то подобное.
Т.к. в остальных случаях вроде всё нормально должно быть.

```
Data value = new Data();
value.Name = 'Name 1';
views[0] = value;

value.Name = 'Name 2';
views[1] = value;
```

Comment: Ага, только весь индекс заполняется одним последним введённым занчением.
____

var x = new Data();
           var mi = new Evnt(2);
          
        x.Name = "Zet";
        mi.Seting[0] = x;
        x.Name = "Zet2";
        mi.Seting[1] = x;

        l.Text += mi.Seting[0].Name + mi.Seting[1].Name;

       получаю весь индекс =  x.Name = "Zet2";

Comment: Каждый раз создавайте новый объект

    x = new Data(); // или в цикле

Answer (score 1):

> Получаю одно и то же значение во всех индексах.

что странно, потому что это только задание длины массива, т.е. вместо всех элементов должно быть null

У меня всё получилось через простую итерацию:

```
namespace Playground
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataList list = new DataList();
            list.PrintList();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class Data
    {
        public int Index;
        public int Number;
        public int AnotherNumber;
    }
    class DataList
    {
        public Data[] List;
        public DataList(int length = 10)
        {
            List = new Data[length];
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                Data item = new Data();
                item.Index = i;
                item.Number = length - i;
                item.AnotherNumber = random.Next(12);
                List[i] = item;
            }
        }
        public void PrintList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < List.Length; i++)
            {
                Data item = List[i];
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("DataList item: index {0}, number {1}, another number {2}", item.Index, item.Number, item.AnotherNumber));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но, конечно, в шарпе лучше пользоваться List до тех пор, пока ресурсы не начинают поджимать.

Answer (score 1):

А что Вам нужно от свойства`Data`?  Вы создаёте пустой массив заданного размера, понятное дело, что там во всех индексах 0. Пройдитесь по индексам массива и заполните их, чем Вам надо, и всего делов.